# How can I properly format this bash if statement?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I'm relatively new to bash and I'm trying to do this:

```
COMPARE2=$(tail -n 1 $LOGFILE)
echo "$COMPARE2"
if [ "$COMPARE" != "$COMPARE2" ]
  then
    echo "Server not responding, killing process..."
#   kill $(ps aux | grep 'craftbukkit.jar' | awk '{print $2}')
fi
```

Essentially, if COMPARE does not match COMPARE2, I want it to execute a command. If it is equal, do nothing.

Currently, COMPARE and COMPARE2 do not match but it executes echo "Server not responding" anyway.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You have a != in the if condition so it's correct that echo echo is executed

Answer (score 0):

!= means "Does not equal", so what your code is saying is:

If Compare does not equal Compare2 then echo "Server not responding, killing process..."

You need to change != to = to check for equality. != checks for *inequality*.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But now it's giving me an "unexpected operator" error.

Comment: @user3273395 Are you trying `==`? `==` isn't a valid operator for single bracket test `[]`, but you can just switch to `[[]]` (which are preferred for most pure-bash cases anyway because of additional functionality) and it should work.

Comment: How would you write that? I tried if [ ["$COMPARE" != "$COMPARE2"] ] and if [[ "$COMPARE" != "$COMPARE2" ]] but it didn't work.

Comment: Also, it's a shell script, I don't think it is pure bash. Sorry, I should have clarified.

Comment: You need spaces before the first and after the last part of the expression, so try `[[ "$COMPARE" != "$COMPARE2" ]]` Right a bash script is a subset of shell scripts.

Comment: `==` is not the correct operator, you need to use `=` for equality between two strings with bash's builtin `[]` util.